# Upload Progress bar within form data

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I try to create an upload progress bar with PHP and jQuery. However, I have a problem when I bring it to the form data. The code is similar like this:

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-form" target="upload-frame">

Suburb:<input type="text" name="txtSuburb" id="txtSuburb">

Picture:
<input type="hidden" id="uid" name="UPLOAD_IDENTIFIER" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Upload!">
<iframe id="upload-frame" name="upload-frame">
</iframe>

<input type="submit" name="DataSubmit" value="Submit Data"/> 
</form>
```

As you can see, I got 2 submit buttons. If I keep the form like this then the form can't submit data to server. It just submits the file to iFrame. If I change the action and target of the form then the upload progress function will not work.

Could anyone please help me to find the solution for this?

I want the user can click on upload button to upload their file. Then they can take the rest to fill the form. When everything is done, they can click on another submit data button to submit their data (included the file) to the server.

Comment: To save yourself anguish maybe you could make use of http://www.plupload.com which is a jQuery upload widget that handles this stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have only one `input` element of type `submit` within your form.

If you want the first button to trigger some Javascript, use a regular input element or even a styled link and attach a Javascript event to it's `onclick` event, then prevent it's default behavior, e.g. by returning `false`.
Like this only the second button will actually submit your form which should do what you're describing.

*In general I'd second @Treffynnon's suggestion to use a existing library for this purpose. These hacks have a tendency to get pretty nasty, especially when it comes to crossbrowser compatibility.*

Comment: I think we need to submit the form twice. The first submit will upload the file and the second submit to send the data to server. Or may be I am wrong. Please correct me and give me some sample code. Thank You!

Comment: If you submit the form, everything within the form will be sent. I can't give you any example, since I' don't know the rest of your application but from what I understand you have to either handle the two parts of the form separately, tying them together using Javascript or e.g. use a Flash uploader instead of the iFrame.